# Google Map Coordinates conversion

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have coordinates with unknown form
for example : X : 187341.9208 , Y : 665722.3982 ,
What projection are these coordinates in? 
The main purpose is to convert those coordinates to Lat and Lng form that will work in Google Maps.

The source of those coordinates are unknown to me, it's a city in Israel. According to Google coordinates to this city is lat: 32.096 , lng: 34.886

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like those coordinates are in the Israeli Transverse Mercator Projection

https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=2039&t_srs=4326&x=187341.9208000&y=665722.3982000

gives {lat: 32.0844147, lng: 34.8643428}, seems pretty close.

[image: screenshot]

```js
function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = {
    lat: 32.0844147,
    lng: 34.8643428
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: '187341.9208,665722.3982'
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```